# how to apply join or innerquery to connect two table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Here MyChildTable contains only id and the parent table contains id + name.
I have written a query to fetch the existing data from the table

```cs
await _dbContext.MyChildTable
    .Where(c => c.CustomerId == **(select customerid from tableParent where customername= reqcustomername)**
```

Here i want to match customerId with the matching customer id from the second table ie tableParent.How to replace the query in to linq to get the proper record.select customerid from tableParent where customername= reqcustomername i want to replace this selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean
so my maybe answer error

**LINQ**

```
 using (entity entityData = new entity())
            {
var checkqry2 = from T1 in entityData.MyChildTable.AsNoTracking()
                join T2 in entityData.tableParent on
                T1.CustomerId equals T2.customerid
                where T1.customerid == "ID" && T2.customername == reqcustomername
                group new { T2.customerid, T2.customername } by new { T1.customerid, T1.customername } into c
                orderby c.Key.customerid
                select new { customername=c.Key.customername, 
                             customerid=c.Key.customerid,   
                };
 
               }
```

you can try entity lambda

**entity lambda**

```
using (entity entityData = new entity())
            {
var query1 = entityData.MyChildTable
             .Join(entityData.tableParent , o => o.CustomerId , p => p.CustomerId , (o, p) => new
                       {
                           o.CustomerId,
                           p.customername,
                       }).Where(o => o.CustomerId == "123" && o.customername == "name").ToList();
              
                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here I want to match customerId with the matching customer id from the
> second table ie tableParent.How to replace the query in to linq to get
> the proper record.select customerid from tableParent where
> customername= reqcustomername i want to replace this selection

Well, lot of way around to handle this kind of scenario. Most easy and convenient way you could consider by using [linq join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) or [linq Enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-7.0)  which you can implement as following:

Sample Data:

```
var childList = new List<ChildTable>()
            {
                new ChildTable(){ Id =101,ChildName = "Child-A",CustomerId = 202},
                new ChildTable(){ Id =102,ChildName = "Child-B",CustomerId = 203},
                new ChildTable(){ Id =103,ChildName = "Child-C",CustomerId = 202},
                new ChildTable(){ Id =104,ChildName = "Child-D",CustomerId = 204},


            };

            var parentList = new List<ParentTable>()
            {
                new ParentTable(){ Id =301,ParentName = "Parent-A",CustomerId = 202},
                new ParentTable(){ Id =302,ParentName = "Parent-B",CustomerId = 202},
                new ParentTable(){ Id =303,ParentName = "Parent-C",CustomerId = 203},
                new ParentTable(){ Id =304,ParentName = "Parent-D",CustomerId = 205},


            };
```

**Linq Query:**

Way One:

```
 var findMatchedByCustId = from child in childList
                                      where (from parent in parentList select parent.CustomerId)
                                      .Contains(child.CustomerId)
                                      select child;
```

**Way Two:**

```
var usingLinqJoin = (from parent in parentList
                                 join child in childList on parent.CustomerId equals child.CustomerId
                                 select parent).ToList().Distinct();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you need more information you could check our official document for [Linq join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/type-relationships-in-linq-query-operations) and [Linq Projction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/project-anonymous-type#example-project-an-anonymous-type-by-creating-objects-in-the-select-clause) here.